# Compiling Netcat with DFLAGS

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I've been trying to compile netcat so that I can use the `-e` option but I am not sure as to how or where to place the custom flags.

So far I've done:

```
./configure
Make
```

and then I edit the Makefile with:

```
DFLAGS = -DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE -DTELNET
```

and then do `make install`.

Is that the correct way to do this?

Comment: Edit the Makefile before running `Make`.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Err... do it ends in error? IMO is not `Make` but `make` (lowercase) also the Makefile should be edited before you run `make`. On other hand, what are you trying to od?

Comment: No, first you edit the makefile, then you run `make` and _then_ `make install`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow the rest of the compiling netcat section in the [hacking with your cat manual](http://www.ihtb.org/security/hacking_with_your_cat.txt). Also add

```
CFLAGS = -O
```

And then:

> ```
> Linux users, modify the netcat.c file and add #include "resolv.h" on line 30.
>
> #include "resolv.h"
> #include "generic.h"            /* same as with L5, skey, etc */
>
> You are now ready to rock. Compile netcat by typing make SYSTEM, 
> replace SYSTEM with your OS.
> ```